Was Origen the first to write of the Son being eternally begotten?
It’s been a minute since I’ve read through the writings of the Ante-Nicene Church Fathers, but from my read through Origen appears to have been the first to record the idea that the Son was eternally begotten.
Earlier Church Fathers were explicit that the Son was born / created at some point. Justin Martyr says that the Son is a lesser, second god begotten from God Almighty like fire-from-fire. Tertullian wrote that there was a time when God was not the Father; a time when the Son did not exist.
Even Origen, despite his belief in the eternal generation of the Son, held the Son to be “a second god as it were” according to the current work I’m reading “Origen of Alexandria: Master Theologian of the Early Church” by John Anthony McGuckin.
Please provide quotes + references to any authors that spoke of the Son as eternally begotten prior to Origen, if there are any. Alternatively, if there are any academic resources affirming that he was the first to put forth such a concept I’d accept that as well.
I am not looking for your personal or denominational interpretation of scripture on this matter for this thread. I am only interested in those writing prior to (and perhaps contemporaries of) Origen
Of Alexandria.

Well, that writing prior to Origen is to be found in the opening verses of the Apostle John's gospel.

@Anne as I noted, not interested in your interpretation of scripture for this thread; I’m just interested in the interpretations of the Church Fathers prior to 255 AD (Origen died in 254 AD).

Which is why I shall not be answering your question! I shall not even quote the pertinent verses without interpretation. If the direct words of the text are not good enough, then why bother with anything else?

@Anne if the text directly and obviously teaches what you think it does - then it shouldn’t be hard to find early Church Fathers who share your view

Of course there are early Church Fathers who agree with John's gospel teaching that the Son of God is eternally begotten. But if you are looking for an authenticated document that uses that precise phrase, then that's like Muslims requiring a statement from Jesus in the Bible, "I am God".

I am skeptical of the phrase (attributed to Origen) “a second god as it were”. I doubt very much that those are Origen's words ; being more likely a misguided paraphrase of his words by a commentator. I can find  no resonance with that phrase in the Coptic Church .net 's explanation of Origen's viewpoint.

@Nigel I’ve given the book reference from which I found it. I agree that a more direct quotation is desirable, and I’ll be following up on it myself. However, it certainly makes sense historically- both sides of the Arian Controversy were debating different aspects of Origen’s school of thought. He was a controversial figure due to his teachings and musings ultimately being contradictory with what became orthodoxy. At any rate, the question doesn’t depend upon how orthodox or unorthodox his views were; I’m just curious as to the earliest instances of the idea that the son is eternally begotten

Well, I would have to agree with @Anne that the earliest instances are in Matthew and Luke - the 'begetting' within the virgin, indicating the presence of a begetting prior to the delivery of a child. And Luke's use of the word monogenes clearly demonstrating the word's spiritual connotation - a purposeful, generational, yet non-gender, relationship. Like many other aspects of doctrine (justification  by faith is an example) it took a while for wise men to arise who saw the depths of the apostles' words and who could then instruct us the more fully, out of all error and confusion.

@NigelJ as noted, I’m not interested in personal / denominational interpretations of the scriptures. You can think the scriptures teach the Trinity and such but at the end of the day the scriptures don’t explicitly teach these things; they are a high level interpretation that requires a systematic approach to the entirety of the scriptures. I can easily present alternatives from a non-Trinitarian perspective. This is a question concerning the origins of a specific doctrinal teaching within the context of the early church.

Yes, you may 'present alternatives' and I may competently answer every single detail from the actual words of the Greek text. That's why the Lord has provided his word in absolute accuracy and in masterful cohesion. Leaving no room for doubt.

@NigelJ you may think that you are able to answer competently, but ultimately you like every Trinitarian will inevitably fallback on mystery and obfuscation when you come up short; like how you are here refusing to answer the actual question.

The question seeks a mention by someone in the very late first century or during the second century (prior to Origen 185-253 AD) who mentions the wording 'eternally begotten'. I think it unlikely, though I would be very interested if some researcher were successful. If one speaks of the Father (God) begetting the Son (God) then one does not need to specify that begetting as 'eternal' that concept already being embedded in the Divine terms 'Father' and 'Son'. The need to specify would have been later than the second century after errors and heresies arose and clarification became necessary.

Nigel’s as alluded in the OP, it was a common enough belief among the early Church Fathers that the Son was a creature; even the Wisdom of God in Proverbs 8. We can look at Church Fathers like Justin Martyr and Tertullian who very clearly did not believe the Son to be eternally begotten as with Origen and later Orthodoxy. They maintained that he was begotten as the first of creation, at the beginning. Tertullian even says there was a time when God was not the Father. So you are very much mistaken to say that any mention of the Father begetting the Son implies that he was eternally begotten

Tertullian was the first Latin writer to use the word trinity.  He spoke extensively of the subordination of the son to the father but not against begotteness.  https://www.dennyburk.com/deep-in-the-weeds-on-monogenes-and-eternal-generation/

@MikeBorden Tertullian taught that there was a time when God was not the Father, a time when the Son did not exist. His conception of the Trinity is not compatible with what became orthodoxy; His views were more compatible with the so-called Arians

Taking a look at the graphic summary of Tertullian's trinity (section 3.1.2 of this article https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/trinity/trinity-history.html#Tertul) wherein at "Time 1" there exists Father/God and Word and it is commented that "At the beginning, God is alone, though he has his own reason within him." and looking at Tertullian's own words to Praxeas, ""You ought to prove plainly, however, your points as we ourselves prove that He made His Word a Son to Himself." it is not so clear that he believed the Son went from non-existence to existence.

@MikeBorden he explicitly states that there was a time when God was not the Father and when the Son did not exist. Any ambiguity is cleared up if you read everything he wrote instead of conveniently ignoring the passage where he is anything but ambiguous

Do you win a lot through condescension or do folks just stop talking to you?  Tertullian also reasons that there was a time when God was neither Lord nor Judge.  In other words, God is not unchanging but is altered by things external to Himself.  Not very sound.  He reasons thus in an attempt to refute that matter is uncreated and eternal.  He brings the Trinity into the discussion only tangentially and it is therefore less than a definition.

@MikeBorden You disagreeing with it doesn’t mean it is unsound. If you actually read his writings you will find that Tertullian was not a fan of Greek Philosophy; he considered it a source of heresy such as with the Gnostics. And he’s not wrong. By all means study Plato but don’t confuse it for scripture. The God of scripture is not the static, emotionless God of the Greek Philosophers. God gets angry and sad. While he doesn’t change his ways - he certainly adapts his plans according to our freewill decisions. God interacts with us in time. Study to understand- not to confirm your biases

@RyanPierceWilliams Tertullian drew a lot upon Stoic philosophy, so we shouldn't pretend philosophy did not color his theology.  There is a difference between changing emotional states (moving from pleased to angry for example) and changing fundamental essence.  God does one and not the other:  "I am the Lord; I change not, therefore you are not consumed, O Jacob."  Tertullian, reasoning from Genesis 1 and 2 and the change in the text from "Elohim" to "Yahweh Elohim"  supposes there was a time when God was not "Yahweh/I am (rendered LORD)".

@RyanPierceWilliams His theory is that, prior to having something to be Lord over (the material universe and specifically Man), God was not Lord.  Not Yahweh.  Not the self existent I AM.  He misunderstands God's Name, I AM, as being merely a function, Lord.  Unsound.

@MikeBorden LORD is not the same as Lord. He doesn’t say anything about being LORD, but of being Lord in the passage in question. You are drawing false conclusions about what he thought.
